# MySQL UPDATE on SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, is it possible to update the selected records on the same query?

For eg., If the query

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM `table`
  WHERE field = "value"
  LIMIT 0,2
```

Return two rows, then on the same query, i need to increment the table's `count` field by 1. Is it possible?

Comment: can you be a bit more precise ?

Comment: @krammer I need to update the selected rows count by 1(to get the number of times it is displayed) after selecting the data. So i think it will better to write both the query as one

Comment: Why don't you write two seperate queries? The one you are asking for is not supported in single query

Comment: @Udhay: I don't think MySQL has anything similar to PostgreSQL's `UPDATE ... RETURNING`. You will have to write two queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible.  The verb `SELECT` only retrieves data (without modifying it); and the verb `UPDATE` only modifies data (without retrieving it).  There is no MySQL verb that will perform both actions.  You will have to use two separate statements.

However, those two statements can be encapsulated within a transaction (if supported by your storage engine) to ensure that they are conducted atomically and/or could be invoked from within a stored procedure to simplify the command that must be issued by your client.  Combining the two one would have:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE PROCEDURE select_and_update(value TEXT)
BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE field = value LIMIT 0,2;
    UPDATE `table` SET count = count + 1 WHERE ...;
  COMMIT;
END;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Then your client need merely do:

```
CALL select_and_update('value');
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes its possible you can write as `UPDATE` query as:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET count = count + 1
WHERE field = "value"
LIMIT 2;
```

or for `LIMIT` with offset try:

```
UPDATE my_table a
       INNER JOIN (SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE field = "value" LIMIT 0, 2) b
             ON a.id = b.id
SET count = count + 1;
```